# Where is the file saved with the path .documentDirectory

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, csv

As the titel rleaves. I'm facing the issue, that I have no clue how to save the csv file to the document of the devices so I can get accesse outside my app. Can any body help?

So far I tried this code.

```
func creatCSV() -> Void {
    let fileName = "Tasks.csv"
    do {
        guard let path = try? FileManager.default.url(
                for: .documentDirectory, 
                in: .allDomainsMask, 
                appropriateFor: nil, 
                create: false
        ).appendingPathComponent(fileName) as NSURL else {
            return
        }
        var csvText = "Date,Task Name,Time Started,Time Ended\n"
        for task in taskArr {
            let newLine = "\(task.date),\(task.name),\(task.startTime),\(task.endTime)\n"
            csvText.append(newLine)
        }
        try csvText.write(to: path as URL, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to create file")
        print("\(error)")
    }
    print("not found")
}
```

But I have no clue where I finde the file after I called the funtion.

Comment: I'd recommend searching for `swift integrate with files app` - one article that could probably help: https://www.appcoda.com/files-app-integration/

Comment: @DongMag Thanks I'll defenitly check it out after work.

Comment: @DongMag Thanks it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short: You have to set in "info.plist" `"Application supports iTunes file sharing"` to `"YES"`